# How to store Google classroom Assignment and assessments data in our SQL database using Google classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

Presently i am working on Google Classroom API to integrate Google Classroom to my .net web application.I am able to store courses details,teachers and students in each course in my SQL server database but i am unable to store  Assignment and assessments related data given by teacher and students marks and no.of students did assignments in time in my Database.How can i achieve this
Your small answer will help us a a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Classroom API currently doesn't provide access to assignment data. You can follow [feature request #3887](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3887) to get updated when this feature is added.